# Hide only those spans which are empty or have no text in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide only those spans which don't have any text.

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="showcase-caption" style="display: block; "> <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_0">This has caption</span>

    </div>
    <div class="showcase-caption" style="display: block;">  <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_1"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="showcase-caption" style="display: block;">  <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_2">This has caption and show show</span>

    </div>
    <div class="showcase-caption" style="display: block;">  <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_3"></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/0mzpLrt3/

Comment: `span:empty` is working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make a slight change to your JavaScript (in the fiddle) to remove or hide the parent of the empty element:

```
$(".img-wrapper span:empty").each( function () {
    $(this).parent().remove(); // or .hide() to hide
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo class selector:

```
span:empty {
    display: none; /* or visibility: hidden */
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that :empty won't work in IE8 or lower.

Comment: The span is being removed.  Do you mean that you want to remove the span's parent div?  If so, see @BenjaminRay's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$(".img-wrapper .showcase-caption span").each(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':empty')) 
          $(this).parent().hide()
});
```

I'm test in http://fiddle.jshell.net/0mzpLrt3/ and works fine

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0mzpLrt3/3/)

Html:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="showcase-caption" > <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_0">This has caption</span>

    </div>
    <div class="showcase-caption">  <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_1"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="showcase-caption">  <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_2">This has caption and show show</span>

    </div>
    <div class="showcase-caption" > <span id="MainContent_ImageCaption_3"></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".img-wrapper span:empty").each( function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
});
```